# Second sinon stub not called in async parallel

Tags: node.js, sinon

I am trying to test the following code:

```
var archive = function(callback){
    call to this.archive() here...
}

var map = function(callback){
    call to this.map() here...
}

async.parallel([map, archive], function(error){
    handle errors here...
})
```

I am testing that the handle errors functionality is working by stubbing the archive and map functions so that one of them returns an error:

```
var mapStub = sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, 'map').yields("mock error",null );
var archiveStub = sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, 'archive').yields(null,null );
```

The problem I am having is that the archiveStub does not seem to be being used, as I am getting errors from a function which is called by that function (which would be expected if that function was called as I have not initialised variables for this test).

I have another test, where the archive function returns an error instead of the map function, and this test passes without seeming to call either of the stubbed methods instead of the stubs.

```
var mapStub = sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, 'map').yields(null,null );
var archiveStub = sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, 'archive').yields("mock error",null );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `yieldsAsync` instead of `yields`, otherwise the error is yielded prematurely (before all the parallel "tasks" have been started) and `async.map()` stops any further processing (using `yields` basically turns it into a synchronous operation).